# devexpress gridview filtering asp ShowFilterRow

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a devexpress gridview within my asp.net page which has a filter row. This in-built control seems to filter based on whether the search term is same as the beginning of the data.

So "Sa" would find "Sam's Chicken" but not "Big Sam". There is a work around that you can enter "%Sa" to find any matches though users are not particularly happy with this.

Does the filtering fire any events and can I handle this rather than use the default?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you set the column's Settins.AutoFilterCondition to the Contains value.  Also, you can set the [ASPxGridView.Settings.ShowFilterRowMenu](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewSettings_ShowFilterRowMenutopic) property to true.  In this case, the end user will be able to set a filter condition for every column